# Connecting to a SQL Server 2008 from Unix with Integrated Authentication or Kerberos

Tags: java, sql-server, security, jdbc, kerberos

How can I connect using JDBC, to a SQL Server Instance that has only Integrated Security,  ***from a Unix Machine?***

In my current scenario, the given Server is configured to use Integrated Security.

I have read about Kerberos, but I didn't quite understand how it works.

What is Mixed Mode?

Is Kerberos set in the SQL Server Instance, and not in the client(Unix)

Does anyone have a more clear guide rather than the one form Microsoft?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg558122.aspx

Are there changes in the Code of my Java Application in case Kerberos comes into play?

Comment: Mixed mode usually means the SQL Server allows both SQL Server and Windows Authentication.  SQL Server allows Windows authentication using either NTLM or Kerberos.  SQL Server is not specifically configured to use NTLM or Kerberos for Windows authentication;  the authentication protocol is negotiated during connection.  The SPN infrastructure needs to be configured before Kerberos can be used.

Comment: So, correct if I am wrong @DanGuzman enabling the Mixed mode, I can use the same user to connect from the Unix Machine? In other words, there is no need to create another user for that SQL Server Database, it is just a matter of enabling SQL Server authentication?

Comment: If SQL Server is configured to allow SQL authentication, the connection string just needs to specify the user and password of an existing SQL Server login.  SQL Server authenticates the login in that case.

Comment: Thank you. IN my case I think I need then a mixed mode. I believe in that, because, that are other applications running that will continue using Integrated Authentication. 
@DanGuzman Do you know how to change to Mixed mode with the same user?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx

Comment: A login in SQL Server is either a Windows login or a SQL login.  It cannot be both so you will need different accounts.  Note you can have a SQL login with the same user name as a Windows user name but without the domain.  For example `CREATE LOGIN [YourDomain\YourUserName] FROM WINDOWS;` and `CREATE LOGIN [YourUserName] WITH PASSWORD = 'asd40db9$*';`.

Comment: In case I can only have domain users. Then I need Kerberos to connect from a Unix Box? @DanGuzman

Comment: You might be able to take advantage of "pass-through authentication" to the SQL Server as described in the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26465897/2144390).