# Apache NiFi with MS SQL Server integration

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, apache-nifi, jtds

I'm about to connect [ApacheNiFi](https://nifi.apache.org) to the MS SQL Server as bellow:

```
1) ApacheNiFi is deployed on Ubuntu 18.04 server

2) ExecuteSQL 1.9.0 processor is using Database Connection Pooling Service
```

---

```
3) DBCPConnectionPool 1.9.0 is using JTDS driver to connect MS SQL Server
   Database Connection URL=
   [
     jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.10.10.1:1433;
     databaseName=MY_DB; 
     domain=MY_DOMAIN;
     authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos;
     trustServerCertificate=true;
     authentication=NotSpecified;useNTLMv2=true
   ]

4) Database Driver Class Name=[net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver]
5) Database Driver Location(s) = [file:///opt/install/nifi-1.9.0/lib/jtds-1.3.1.jar]
6) Database User = [myuser@MY_DOMAIN]
7) Password = [*****]
```

---

```
 8) Authorization is done on Active Directory located in SERVERS_DOMAIN

 9) I can logon server from my Excell/Access with no issue.
10) However my NiFi is getting response back
    [
       Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Login failed. The login is from an untrusted 
       domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication 
       atnet.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
    ]
```

Please advise how such issue can be resolved.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't added your Ubuntu host to the Windows Domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe you have to specify url with domain:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://${host}:1433/${db};useNTLMv2=true;domain=${domain}
```

and user should be without domain

doc: http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html

Comment: Error message is again:  The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication

Comment: have you set `;useNTLMv2=true` ?

Comment: btw there was a discussion about this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26274472/authenticating-to-a-sql-server-instance-as-a-windows-user-via-jdbc

Comment: Yes, useNTLMv2=true;